# How to save data to mysql after looping a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to PHP and i'm having a multidimensonal array. S i dug around about how to loop through the said array. Fortunately i got around that, but cannot seem to get each individual value separately. Let me show you what i mean:

This is my array:

```js
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [city] => Nairobi
            [email] => dummy@email.com
            [land_mark] => dummylandmark
            [order_at] => dummytime
            [payment_mode] => dummymode
            [phone] => dummyphone
            [receipt_code] => dummycode
            [shipping_mode] => dummymode
            [user_name] => dummyuser
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [amount] => 2000
                            [name] => dummyname
                            [p_id] => 
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [subtotal] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [amount] => 2500
                            [name] => dummyname1
                            [p_id] => 
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [subtotal] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

JSON Array:

```js
[
  
  {
    "receipt_code": "2016-12-17_23:09:55_obpekqaqdn",
    "payment_mode": "Cash On Delivery",
    "city": "Nairobi",
    "email": "admin@buyathome.com",
    "phone": "0715611306",
    "order_at": "2016-12-17 23:09:55",
    "user_name": "Admin",
    "shipping_mode": "I'll Collect Myself",
    "land_mark": "Postal office"
  },
  {
    "products": [
      {
        "amount": 9000,
        "description": "Experience with the Itel phone ",
        "id": 45,
        "quantity": "1",
        "title": "Itel"
      },
      {
        "amount": 200,
        "description": "Do BBS fee r be ft gr",
        "id": 46,
        "quantity": "1",
        "title": "The he hd"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the snippet:

```js
//  Multi-dementional Source Array
//convert json object to php associative array
 $data = json_decode(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $jsondata), true);
//  Output array
displayArrayRecursively($data);

/**
 * Recursive function to display members of array with indentation
 *
 * @param array $arr Array to process
 * @param string $indent indentation string
 */
function displayArrayRecursively($arr, $indent='') {
    if ($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                //
                displayArrayRecursively($value, $indent . '--');
            } else {
                //  Output should be inserted into mysql database
                //but this method outputs all values into a single string
                echo "$value";

             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```js
Nairobi
dummy@email.com
dummylandmark
dummytime
dummymode
dummyphone
dummycode
dummymode
dummyuser
2000
dummyname

1
1
2500
dummyname1

1
1
```

My code for insertion:

```js
$sql_query="insert into purchases (user_name, city, p_id,p_name,sub_total,quantity,email,landmark,order_at,payment_mode,phone,receipt_code,shipping_mode ) values ('$user_name','$city','$p_id','$p_name','$sub_total','$quantity','$email','$landmark','$order_at','$payment_mode','$phone','$receipt_code','$shipping_mode');";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query)){
 //echo "<h3> Data Insert success</h3>";
    $response["success"]=true;
 $response["message"]="Purchase created successfully";
 echo json_encode($response);
}
else{
  $response["success"]=false;
  $response["error"]=mysqli_error($conn);
 $response["message"]="Creating purchase failed, please retry";
 echo json_encode($response);
}
```

As one string. But i wanted to add each individual value into mysql database. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any code written for insertion ?

Comment: Yes see my edit above

Comment: I suspect the output you get echo $value is not a single string, it is written inside for and outputs the value for each loop. Still its little unclear the variable you're inserting is different from the above what you're getting in array

Comment: Okay yes i see it clearer now.But what are your suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using:

```js
foreach($data['products'] as $key => $val)
{
 $product_id = $val['p_id)'];
 $product_name = $val['name'];
 $product_subtotal = $val['amount'];
 $product_quantity = $val['quantity'];

print_r ($product_name);
    //insert into mysql table
    $sql_query="insert into purchases (user_name, city, p_id,p_name,sub_total,quantity,email,landmark,order_at,payment_mode,phone,receipt_code,shipping_mode ) values ('$user_name','$city','$product_id','$product_name','$product_subtotal','$product_quantity','$email','$landmark','$order_at','$payment_mode','$phone','$receipt_code','$shipping_mode');";

if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query)){
 //echo "<h3> Data Insert success</h3>";
    $response["success"]=true;
 $response["message"]="Purchase created successfully";
 echo json_encode($response);
}
else{
  $response["success"]=false;
  $response["error"]=mysqli_error($conn);
 $response["message"]="Creating purchase failed, please retry";
 echo json_encode($response);
} 
}
```

Will update function with sql injections

Comment: but i think this will not work perfectly for more values

Comment: Please let me know how i can improve it.

Comment: give me your $data array value then i will give you full executable code with testing

Comment: @Faisal see my edit above, please do explain your code so i can understand the steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //Code by :: GM

    //REPLACE $data with your data source and include your DB connection


        $data = ['city' => 'Nairobi', 'email' => 'dummy@email.com', 'products' => [array('amount' => 2000, 'name' => 'dummy_product_name', 'p_id' => 1, 'quantity' => 1, 'subtotal' => 1), array('amount' => 2500, 'name' => 'second_dummy_product_name', 'p_id' => 2, 'quantity' => 7, 'subtotal' => 1)]];

        $insert_query_int = 'INSERT INTO purchases SET ';
        $insert_query = $insert_query_int;
        $query_statement_array=[];
        $part_1_store='';
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            //checks if value is string or an array
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                //if value is string

                $part_1 = "$key = '".$value."', ";
                $part_1_store.=$part_1;
                $insert_query.= $part_1;

            } else {
                //if value is an array
                //FOR EACH PRODUCT
                $product_index = 0;
                foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {

                    foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                        //add product details to the query statement
                        $insert_query .= "$key3 = '" . $value3 . "', ";

                    }


                   //PRIMING THE LOOP
                    if($product_index!=0){
                       //add product details to the query statement
                        $insert_query = $insert_query_int.$insert_query;
                    }


                    //Remove last comma from query string
                    $insert_query = rtrim(trim($insert_query),',');
                    //Store query statement in an array
                    $query_statement_array[] =$insert_query;
                    $insert_query = $part_1_store;


                    $product_index++;
                }


            }


        }


        //INSERT DATA TO DB
        if (!$conn->multi_query(implode($query_statement_array,';'))) {
           //fail response
            $response["success"]=false;
            $response["error"]=mysqli_error($conn);
            $response["message"]="Creating purchase failed, please retry";
            echo json_encode($response);
            die();
        }

        do {
            if ($res = $conn->store_result()) {
                $res->free();
            }
        } while ($conn->more_results() && $conn->next_result());


        //success response
        $response["success"]=true;
        $response["message"]="Purchase created successfully";
        echo json_encode($response);

// you should consider normalizing your tables
```

Comment: let me get back to you when i test this